# jquery inArray usage

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to find some words in some array and I did something like this:

```
    $("#get").click(function(){
    $(".name").each(function(){
        var fisier = $(this).text();
        alert($.inArray("migr", fisier));
    });
});
```

I have "migr" in almost every fisier var but I get only -1. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: It will match the exact word only..

Comment: `fisier` is just a string not an array.

Comment: can you provide the html and the data in that

Comment: fisier variable is string not array & you try to redeclare it again and again

Comment: try splitting the string `fisier` like `fisier.split(/\b/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the keyword with JavaScript indexOf method. This is check for each element of the array:

```
$("#get").click(function(){
    $(".name").each(function(){
        var fisier = $(this).text();       
        if(fisier.indexOf("migr") !=-1){
           alert('Keyword found');
        }else{
           alert('Keyword not found');
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> With the help of **inArray** function you can check value exists in array
>   or not. $.inArray function return the index of element. If element not
>   exist in array it will return -1. So, we can check it very simply
>   weather a value exist in array or not.

Answer (score 1):

inArray returns the index of the element in the array, not a boolean indicating if the item exists in the array.

So, to check if an item is in the array, use:

```
if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray)!==-1)
```

or

```
if($.inArray("test", myarray)!==-1)
```

as inArray will return -1, if the element was not found.

Comment: If you want to return a boolean, use a tilde (~). `if (!~$.inArray(0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) { 
// returns false, not -1 }`.

Answer (score 0):

`fisier` is just a string not an array.

I guess this is what you want:

```
$("#get").click(function(){
    var names = $('.name').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    });
    alert($.inArray("migr", names));
});
```